# A function to cycle through opened directories only

Tags: emacs, elisp

I would like to implement a function that would let me cycle only through directory buffers that are open, and skip files or scratch buffers.
How would I go about that?

Comment: This looks pretty close to what you may be looking for -- set `my-ido-ignore-dired-buffers` to `nil` and put in an exclusion for files:  http://scottfrazersblog.blogspot.com/2010/01/emacs-filtered-buffer-switching.html  It even contains the bonus of a font-lock example relating to your other question.

Comment: Do you want a library function that returns a list (or takes a function argument), or an interactive function?

Comment: I am looking for an interactive function that I can bind to an F-key to simply flip between opened directories and another function to switch between opened files

Comment: Thanks lawlist...that is indeed very close.
I am looking more into it right now to see if I can customize it to switch between directories and files.

Comment: Lawlist...I am liking the blog you mentioned...however, the coloring and ignoring of buffers doesnt work. I think it needs to be updated to the new iflip library. Do you have the updated code?

Comment: The cycling now works but the coloring did not.
I fixed it by adding:
(setq iflipb-ignore-buffers 'my-bs-ignore-buffer)

Now I am trying to set ignored directories to nil and ignore buffers to all file types so I could only cycle between directories...but it is not working:
(defvar my-bs-never-show-regexps '("*.[sch]")
  "*Buffer regexps to never show when buffer switching.")

What am in doing wrong?

Comment: Found the solution:
This will exclude files from the switching:
(defvar my-bs-never-show-regexps '("\\(.*\\.\\([sch]\\)$\\)")
  "*Buffer regexps to never show when buffer switching.")

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at tabbar mode -- you can define the groups to anything you want (e.g., `dired`), and cycle between groups with `tabbar-backward-group` and `tabbar-forward-group`:

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TabBarMode

`tabbar-buffer-list-function` can be used to further define whether certain files are displayed (or hidden).

`tabbar-buffer-groups` is the default group which can be modified with `setq` to whatever you want.  If you want to create alternative methods of grouping, you can use `tabbar-buffer-groups-function`.

If `dired` is a group, then you can switch between those buffers by using `(setq tabbar-cycle-scope 'tabs)` with `tabbar-backward` and `tabbar-forward`.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to have a go at implementing something,
have a look at `Buffer-menu-mode`. It's already got a toggle <kbd>T</kbd> for
showing only files.
And then it's just a matter to see how it builds the list
and filter it with

```
(eq major-mode 'dired-mode)
```

The source is quite small at strangely 665 lines.

Answer (score 0):

I use buffer-stack for this.

I wrote two different functions that use that package: one for switching between dired buffers, and other for switching between buffers of the same mode I am.  I use both intensively.  This is how I do it:

```
;; For shorter keybindings
(defmacro command (&rest body)
  `(lambda ()
     (interactive)
     ,@body))

(defvar buffer-stack-mode)

(defun buffer-op-by-mode (op &optional mode)
  (let ((buffer-stack-filter 'buffer-stack-filter-by-mode)
        (buffer-stack-mode (or mode major-mode)))
    (funcall op)))

(defun buffer-stack-filter-by-mode (buffer)
  (with-current-buffer buffer
    (equal major-mode buffer-stack-mode)))

(global-set-key [(meta kp-7)]
                (command (buffer-op-by-mode 'buffer-stack-up)))
(global-set-key [(meta kp-9)]
                (command (buffer-op-by-mode 'buffer-stack-down)))
(global-set-key [(meta kp-3)]
                (command (buffer-op-by-mode 'buffer-stack-down 'dired-mode)))
(global-set-key [(meta kp-1)]
                (command (buffer-op-by-mode 'buffer-stack-up 'dired-mode)))
```

**EDIT:**

I include the macro I use for command keybindings

Comment: Thanks juanleon....
When I added your code to my dotemacs file I get this message on start up:
Symbol's function definition is void: command

Comment: @Ammari, ooops... I forgot to include a convenience macro I use.  Edited.

Comment: Something is not right. First of all you have an extra ) at the end.
Then, I changed the key binding to be f1 -- f4 like this:
(global-set-key [f1]
                (command (buffer-op-by-mode 'buffer-stack-up)))
I still get this message:
funcall: Symbol's function definition is void: buffer-stack-up

Comment: You need buffer stack http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/buffer-stack.el (I removed the extra paren, thanks for pointing it)

Comment: Even when including buffer-stack.el I still get these messages:
if: Symbol's function definition is void: decf
if: Symbol's function definition is void: incf [2 times]
if: Symbol's function definition is void: decf
if: Symbol's function definition is void: decf

Comment: It seems buffer-stack is using cl package without a proper "require".  I never noticed because cl is a dependency for other packages I use.  You can fix that adding `(require 'cl)` in your config file.

Answer (score 0):

**[Icicles](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/Icicles)** offers a couple ways to do this.

- Start in a Dired buffer and do `C-0 C-x b TAB`
- `C-x b`, then `C-x m +`, then enter `dired-mode` (using completion), then `TAB`

Those give you only Dired buffers as the available candidates, which you can then match by name.
You can cycle among the buffers that match your input, using arrow keys (`C-up`, `C-down`).  Use `RET` or `C-g` to end.

- Prefix arg `0` means the candidates are the buffers in the same mode as the current buffer --- hence the first option above.
- When completing, `C-x C-m +` prompts you for a mode and then filters out all candidates whose mode is not the same as or derived from the mode you enter (in this case, `dired-mode`) --- hence the second option above.

`C-x b` is bound in `Icicle` mode to `icicle-buffer`.  If you want to open the buffers in different windows then use `C-x 4 b` (`icicle-buffer-other-window`).

See http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Buffer-Name_Input for more info.